# Looking for work-around for inability of DataGridView control to bind to hierarchical (OO) data

Tags: winforms, data-binding, controls

It would seem that the DataGridView control can only bind to data sources that are flat (all the Properties are primative types).  My data is hierarchal. For example:

```
    interface INestedObj
{
    string Prop3 { get; }
}

interface IParentObj
{
    public string Prop1 { get; }
    public string Prop2 { get; }
    public INestedObj NestedObj { get; }
}
```

Given this, how does one bind to an object implementing IParentObj?  Eventually you are faced with having to do something like this:

```
grid.Columns["prop1Col"].DataPropertyName = "Prop1";
grid.Columns["prop2Col"].DataPropertyName = "Prop2";

grid.Columns["prop3Col"].DataPropertyName = "How to display Prop3?";

grid.Columns["prop3Col"].DataPropertyName = "NestedObj.Prop3"; // does not work
```

I am looking for advice and/or work-arounds.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that came to me at the end of a long day.

I used a Linq query and projection to create an anonymous type that displays the proper information in the DataGridView.

```
var query = from pt in parentObjCollection
  select new {Prop1=pt.Prop1, Prop2=pt.Prop2, NestedObj.Prop3=pt.NestedObj.Prop3};
```

I had to supply the proper value (NestedObj.Prop3) to the DataPropertyName property to get the value to display in the grid.

When I have more time I am going to try and implement Bradley's solution.

Comment: This is a vastly more elegant solution, but you have to sacrifice things like change notification (if your objects supported it in the first place, I don't know). One last thing you might want to look into is the `ITypedList` interface, which a collection can implement in order to expose custom properties. It's a little less flakey than the `TypeDescriptorProvider` solution I posted, upon reflection.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* expose properties from `INestedObj` for binding, but the solution is **very** messy.To give some background, all WinForms controls which support databinding use `TypeDescriptor` to determine which properties exist on the objects they're binding to. Through `TypeDescriptionProvider` and `CustomTypeDescriptor`, you can override the default behaviour and thusly add/hide properties - in this case, hiding the `NestedObj` property and replacing it with all of the properties on the nested type.

The technique i'm going to show has 2 (big-ish) caveats:

1. Since you're working with interfaces (and not concrete classes), you have to add the custom type descriptor at runtime.
2. The custom type descriptor needs to be able to create a concrete instance of `IParentObj`, therefore it must know one such class which has a default constructor.

(Please excuse the lengthy code)

First, you need a way of wrapping a `PropertyDescriptor` from the nested type so that it can be accessed from the parent type:

```
public class InnerPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor {
    private PropertyDescriptor innerDescriptor;

    public InnerPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor owner, 
        PropertyDescriptor innerDescriptor, Attribute[] attributes)
        : base(owner.Name + "." + innerDescriptor.Name, attributes) {
        this.innerDescriptor = innerDescriptor;
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) {
        return innerDescriptor.CanResetValue(((IParentObj)component).NestedObj);
    }
    public override Type ComponentType {
        get { return innerDescriptor.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override object GetValue(object component) {
        return innerDescriptor.GetValue(((IParentObj)component).NestedObj);
    }
    public override bool IsReadOnly {
        get { return innerDescriptor.IsReadOnly; }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType {
        get { return innerDescriptor.PropertyType; }
    }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) {
        innerDescriptor.ResetValue(((IParentObj)component).NestedObj);
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) {
        innerDescriptor.SetValue(((IParentObj)component).NestedObj, value);
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) {
        return innerDescriptor.ShouldSerializeValue(
            ((IParentObj)component).NestedObj
        );
    }
}
```

Then you need to write a custom type descriptor that exposes the properties from the nested type:

```
public class ParentObjDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor {
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(
        Attribute[] attributes) {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties
            = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor outer in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(
            new ParentObj() /* concrete implementation of IParentObj */, 
            attributes, true)) {
            if (outer.PropertyType == typeof(INestedObj)) {
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor inner in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(
                    typeof(INestedObj))) {
                    properties.Add(new InnerPropertyDescriptor(outer, 
                        inner, attributes));
                }
            }
            else {
                properties.Add(outer);
            }
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

...and then you need a way of exposing the descriptor from above:

```
public class ParentObjDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider {
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, 
        object instance) {
        return new ParentObjDescriptor();
    }
}
```

Finally, at run-time (before you bind to the `DataGridView`), you must associate the type description provider with the `IParentObj` interface. You can't do this at compile-time because `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute` can't be placed on interfaces...

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new ParentObjDescriptionProvider(), typeof(IParentObj));
```

I tested this by binding a `DataGridView` to an `IParentObj[]` and, low and behold, it creates columns for `Prop1`, `Prop2` and `NestedObj.Prop3`.

You have to ask yourself, though... is it really worth all that effort?

Comment: Wow, thank you Bradley.  You get the completness trophy. Last night I was able to work out a different (simpler ???) solution which I will post presently.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably add an unbound column for "NestedObj.Prop3" and manually handle its value.  To get the column populated, handle the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView, get the DataBoundItem from the current row and get the Prop3 from that.  To update the data source, handle the CellValidated event to update the DataBoundItem.

There may be more appropriate events to use than the ones I mentioned, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is to create a Self property.  See this solution:
[Databinding a combobox column to a datagridview per row (not the entire column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916312/databinding-a-combobox-column-to-a-datagridview-per-row-not-the-entire-column)