# Use a object property as the DisplayMember in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I want to use a property of an object that's inside an object.
Is there a way to achieve this?

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:80");
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.DisplayMember = **"Address.Authority"**; //Note: Address.Authority is an property inside the WebProxy object
listBox.Items.Add(proxy);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209141/looking-for-work-around-for-inability-of-datagridview-control-to-bind-to-hierarch/4217317), it is essentially asking the same thing - the principle does not change between `DataGridView` and `ListBox`. Short answer: it's possible, but convoluted.

Comment: I used the sabe approach that OP and created a new object that contained my WebProxy object and a string that gives me the Authority of the proxy. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about you subclass `WebProxy` to, for instance, `WebProxyEx` and implement the [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) interface which *sort of(expects an object that implements the IList or IListSource interfaces)* is a pre-requisite to use the `.DataSource` property of listbox. Like following:

```
class WebProxyEx : WebProxy, IList
    {
        private object[] _contents = new object[8];
        private int _count;

        public WebProxy w;

        public WebProxyEx(string address)
        {
            _count = 0;
            w = new WebProxy(address);
            this.Add(w.Address.Authority);
        }
...
```

And use it like:

```
ListBox lb;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebProxyEx w = new WebProxyEx("127.0.0.1:80");//Use your sub class
    lb = new ListBox();
    this.Controls.Add(lb);

    lb.DataSource = w;//assign the datasource.
    //lb.DisplayMember = "Address.Authority"; //Automatically gets added in the WebProxEx constructor.

}
```

**Gives following output in the listbox:**

> 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know if its necessary to implement IList as I already have a List<WebProxy> as my datasource.

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource%28VS.71%29.aspx) for `.DataSource` property; *>An object that implements the IList interface, such as a DataSet or an Array*